# How to maintain state of a dialog component in a custom rally application using the rally sdk 2.1?

Tags: rally

So I am playing with the rally sdk to build custom applications for rally, and I'm trying to have some kind of to do list. I am implementing it using a rally textfield and rally dialogs. It doesn't have a perfect functionality yet, but what I am trying to do is maintain the state of the dialog boxes that I add, so that when I refresh the app they are still there. I haven't figured it out yet, and I can't really seem to get it from reading the rally guides on maintaining state.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    stateful: true,
    componentCls: 'app',

    getState: function() {
        return {
            dialogs: this.dialogs
        };
    },

    applyState: function(state) {
        this.dialogs = state.dialogs;
    },

    doLayout: function() {
        var me = this;
        var textField = Ext.create('Rally.ui.TextField', {
            fieldLabel: 'Add task:',
            listeners: {
                scope: me, 
                specialkey: me._checkEnter
            }
        });

        me.add(textField);
    },

    launch: function() {
        this.doLayout();
        this.taskCounter = 0;
        this.yPosition = 50;
        this.dialogs = [];
    },

    _checkEnter: function(field, event) {
        if (event.getKey() == event.ENTER) {
            this._onEnter(field);
        }
    },

    _onEnter: function(field) {
        this.taskCounter = this.taskCounter + 1;
        var dialog = Ext.create(Rally.ui.dialog.Dialog, {
            context: this.getContext(),
            id: (99990 + this.taskCounter).toString(),
            autoShow: true,
            autoCenter: false,
            draggable: false,
            closable: true,
            modal: false,
            width: 300,
            x: 100,
            y: this.yPosition,
            title: 'Task ' + this.taskCounter,
            items: {
                xtype: 'component',
                html: field.getRawValue(),
                padding: 10
            }
        })

        this.yPosition = this.yPosition + 100;
    }
});
```

****EDIT****

So I've been trying to make this work. I kept trying to maintain state between page refreshes and when navigating away, and started testing this by using an array to store different strings, and see if they would still be there when coming back to the app. Every time I type something into the field box, and press enter, a dialog box is created, and I call saveState(), and attempt to save a string with an ID for the dialog box that was created. But, it seems that the getState function only saves the state the first time is called (on the first enter), because when I refresh or come back to the app, the only string that is persisted is the id of the first dialog box created, but not of the following ones. Is this an error with the saveState function from the SDK, or am I using it wrong? Thanks. Here is the code:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
stateful: true,
componentCls: 'app',

getState: function() {
    console.log('getting state');

    if(this.dialogs.length > 0) {
        console.log('this.dialogs from getState:', this.dialogs);
        var newState = {
            currentDialogs: this.dialogs
        };
        console.log(newState);
        return newState;
    }
    return null;
},

applyState: function(state) {
    console.log('applying state');
    console.log('current state:', state);

    if(state.currentDialogs) {
        this.dialogs = state.currentDialogs;    
        console.log('this.dialogs after applying state:', this.dialogs);
    }
    else {
        this.dialogs = [];
    }
},

doLayout: function() {
    var me = this;
    var textField = Ext.create('Rally.ui.TextField', {
        fieldLabel: 'Add task:',
        listeners: {
            scope: me, 
            specialkey: me._checkEnter
        }
    });

    me.add(textField);
},

launch: function() {
    this.dialogs = this.dialogs;
    this.doLayout();
    this.taskCounter = 0;
    this.yPosition = 50;
},

_checkEnter: function(field, event) {
    if (event.getKey() === event.ENTER) {
        this._onEnter(field);
    }
},

_onEnter: function(field) {
    this.taskCounter = this.taskCounter + 1;
    var dialog = Ext.create(Rally.ui.dialog.Dialog, {
        context: this.getContext(),
        autoShow: true,
        autoCenter: false,
        draggable: false,
        closable: true,
        modal: false,
        width: 300,
        x: 100,
        y: this.yPosition,
        title: 'Task ' + this.taskCounter,
        items: {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: field.getRawValue(),
            padding: 10
        }
    });

    this.yPosition = this.yPosition + 100;
    this.dialogs.push((99990 + this.taskCounter).toString());
    this.saveState();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a head scratcher.  Turns out there is some optimization in the stateful layer for not persisting state if it thinks the value didn't change.  Because in your getState method you are returning the same dialogs array instance that is used and modified by the app it always thinks the value is current and so does not re-persist it.

So if you just tweak your getState to return a new array each time you should be good to go:

```
 var newState = {
     currentDialogs: [].concat(this.dialogs)
 };
```

Once that is in place each time you add a task you will see a call to update the preference in the network tab.

Then you'll just have to add code in the launch method to look at the current state and re-add the tasks that have already been added.

```
_.each(this.dialogs, function(dialog) {
    this._addDialog(dialog.title, dialog.html); //todo: implement
}, this);
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that helped a lot. I also thought it could be something like that, don't know why the concat solution didn't come to mind. Anyway, one more thing, is there a way to make this persisted data available to all of the users on a rally subscription without having to use an external database as the storage model?